# React hydration - Text content did not match

Tags: reactjs, apollo, server-side-rendering

I have a NestJS (Express) backend with the Apollo GraphQL server. I have successfully wired up the SSR process and I can 100% verify that HTML, including Apollo initial state, is getting properly generated on the server.
The issue is the very weird behavior during hydration: only the very first JSX js expression `{}` in a given tag gets hydrated. Here's an example, I'm SSRing a Cat type:

Page source shows correct data:

```
<span>Ace 9</span>
<script>window.__APOLLO_STATE__ = {"Cat:1":{"id":1,"__typename":"Cat","name":"Ace","age":9},"ROOT_QUERY":{"__typename":"Query","cats":[{"__ref":"Cat:1"}]}}</script>
```

And the component is acting weird

```
  const { data } = useQuery<Cats>(findAll, {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  })
  const cat = data?.cats[0]
  return (
    <>
      <span>
        {cat?.name} {cat?.age}
      </span>
    </>
  )
```

This will error as `Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Ace 9" Client: "Ace"`. If I would swap positions of `{cat?.name}` and `{cat?.age}` the error would become `Server: "9 Ace" Client: "9"`. But if I give each expression its own tag error doesn't occur:

```
<span>{cat?.name}</span> <span>{cat?.age}</span>
```

If I put data into a single string unsurprisingly it doesn't occur as well:

```
const a = `${cat?.name} ${cat?.age}`
return <>{a}</>
```

I've banged my head against this wall for an entire day now, I would really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: https://lihautan.com/hydrating-text-content/